Incrementing Key in Simple React To Do App
I have an incrementing key in my React To Do App so I can filter out certain tasks with an id identifier. For some reason, I have to declare and define my id outside of the main function. Why can't I declare and define it inside the main function? Will this affect my website during production since it's a component that gets exported to the main app?
import { useState } from "react";

//incrementing variable outside of main function
let nextId = 1;

//main function
const ToDoList = () => {

    //I make an initial list with only one task so the list renders something at the start, obj in arr brackets
    const initialList = [{ id: 0, taskName: "Example Task" }];

    //set up useState for list and setlist as well as inputvalue and setinputvalue
    const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");

    //id increments with each add goal click, but incrementing variable has to be declared and defined outside main function
    function handleAddClick() {
        if (inputValue.length > 0) {
            setList([...list, { id: nextId++, taskName: inputValue }]);
        }
        setInputValue("");
    }

    //delete tasks by rendering with filter method on ids
    function handleDeleteClick(id) {
        console.log(id);
        setList([...list.filter((item) => item.id !== id)]);
    }

    return (
        <>
          <ul id="list">
            {list.map((item) => {
            return (
                <>
                  <li key={item.id}>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    {item.taskName}
                    <span onClick={() =>
                                      handleDeleteClick(item.id)}>&#10060;
                                    </span>
                  </li>
                </>
                    );
                })}
        </ul>
        <section>
          <input
            onKeyUp={(e) => {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
            handleAddClick();
                       }
                    }}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            id="addGoal"
            placeholder="Add a Goal here!">
                  </input>
          <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add Goal!</button>
          <textarea placeholder="Here's some space to use as a place to type your 
                    thoughts!">
                  </textarea>
        </section>
          </>
    );
};

export default ToDoList;

This isn't as important, but I also don't understand why I get a lint error on line 23, column 29 from TypeScript saying "Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type. It's the function handleAddClick that has the id argument that gets the error. I try to say it's a number, but it doesn't work. I know it's getting a property from an object which is a number, but I don't know how to write the typing.

i would recommend by creating a type or an interface for list and use this throughout your app so that all your objects have types instead of simply any. so something like interface List {id: number; taskName: string}. With this interface you could update your initial list to have a type and your list usestate will now have a type.

@RaphaelCanciani I've tried using an interface before for my arrays of objects. For some reason it just gives me lint errors everywhere. I think it's because interfaces only work for objects, but I have arrays of objects instead of just objects. JSX/TSX/React uses map/filter/iterating methods on arrays to keep track of elements with keys. I've tried using brackets after the interface to specify for typing, but that also doesn't seem to work. At this point, I feel like I just need to read through interfaces as a whole from TypeScript documentation.

I use arrays with interfaces all the time and there are no such errors, but you are saying that you keep having linting issues, could you possibly show your config file. It's also possible that you are not using your interface and arrays correctly, I'll write an answer with how I would use interfaces here.

@RaphaelCanciani /* Linting */     "strict": true,     "noUnusedLocals": true,     "noUnusedParameters": true,     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true I didn't include the whole tsconfig file because it's too long for here apparently.

Here is what the code should look like with a ListType interface
import { useState } from "react";

//incrementing variable outside of main function
let nextId = 1;

interface ListType {
  id: number;
  taskName: string;
}

//main function
const ToDoList = () => {

    //I make an initial list with only one task so the list renders something at the start, obj in arr brackets
    const initialList: ListType[] = [{ id: 0, taskName: "Example Task" }];

    //set up useState for list and setlist as well as inputvalue and setinputvalue
    const [list, setList] = useState<ListType[]>(initialList);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");

    //id increments with each add goal click, but incrementing variable has to be declared and defined outside main function
    function handleAddClick() {
        if (inputValue.length > 0) {
            setList([...list, { id: nextId++, taskName: inputValue }]);
        }
        setInputValue("");
    }

    //delete tasks by rendering with filter method on ids
    function handleDeleteClick(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
        setList([...list.filter((item) => item.id !== id)]);
    }

    return (
        <>
          <ul id="list">
            {list.map((item: ListType) => {
            return (
                <>
                  <li key={item.id}>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    {item.taskName}
                    <span onClick={() =>
                                      handleDeleteClick(item.id)}>&#10060;
                                    </span>
                  </li>
                </>
                    );
                })}
        </ul>
        <section>
          <input
            onKeyUp={(e) => {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
            handleAddClick();
                       }
                    }}
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            id="addGoal"
            placeholder="Add a Goal here!">
                  </input>
          <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add Goal!</button>
          <textarea placeholder="Here's some space to use as a place to type your 
                    thoughts!">
                  </textarea>
        </section>
          </>
    );
};

export default ToDoList;

Now I don't know how you handle your nextId but that would be another issue if that doesn't work.

Wow, yea, that worked. For some reason, I tried this earlier, but I am learning TypeScript while learning React. Thank you for helping with that issue. I have no lint errors now. Don't worry about the other issue. Was stressing about how to rewrite this whole code based off the single typing lint issue. Thanks again!

@Shuumi hey no problem man the pleasure is all mine, I have a hunch that you were forgetting the [] when defining the type, but practice makes perfect :) you go this. Also don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted solution if it worked so that others know that the problem has been solved.
